# Show $C(t)=(2\cos^3(t),\sin(2t),2\sin(t))$ is on the intersection of $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and $x^2+y^2=2x$

Tags: analytic-geometry, curves

Given a curve defined as: $$C(t)=(2\cos^2(t),\sin(2t),2\sin(t))$$ for $0\le t\le2\pi$

Show that the curve is on the intersection of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and  $x^2+y^2=2x$.

---

The intersection of the two equation satisfies:

$$x=2-\frac{z^2}{2}$$

I think the curve is on the the intersection of the two curves if :
$$2\cos^3(t)=2-\frac{4\sin^2(t)}{2}$$

$$\cos^3(t)=\cos^2(t)$$

For all $0\le t\le2\pi$.

But solving the equation implies this is not true in general.

So what is the main strategy and how should I continue?

Comment: Why don’t you simply check that the curve $C$ lies in both the surfaces?

Comment: I think the given definition of the curve is wrong. See whether the curve is $$C(t) = (2 \cos^2 t, \sin (2t), 2 \sin t) $$.

Comment: @45465 That's nice..

Answer (score 1):

### Check if it belongs to the first surface

Replacing the curve in the first equation we get
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 
4\cos^4(t )+ \sin^2(2t) + 4\sin^2(t) =4\cos^4(t )+ 4\sin^2(t)\cos^2(t) + 4\sin^2(t)$$
which is
$$4\cos^4(t )+ \sin^2(2t) + 4\sin^2(t) =4\cos^2(t)[\cos^2(t) + \sin^2(t)] + 4\sin^2(t) = 4\cos^2(t) + 4\sin^2(t) = 4$$
So $C(t)$ is on the first surface.

### Check if it belongs to the second surface

Replacing the curve in the second equation we get
$$x^2 + y^2 = 4\cos^4(t )+ \sin^2(2t) =4\cos^4(t )+ 4\sin^2(t)\cos^2(t) =4\cos^2(t)[\cos^2(t) + \sin^2(t)]=4\cos^2(t)=2x$$
So $C(t)$ is on the second surface.

Answer (score 0):

If the curve is  $$C(t) = (2 \cos^2 t, \sin (2t), 2 \sin t), $$ then, as @Logos said, it is just a matter of substituting it in the equations and checking that it indeed lies on the surfaces.